# Changing file name in cmd using "ren"

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to change the file name of "summary-SUCCESS.txt" or "summary-FAILED.txt" to add text to the front of the file name such as:

"Name1-summary-SUCCESS.txt"

"Name2-summary-SUCCESS.txt"

"Name3-summary-SUCCESS.txt"

... and so on

I am currently using the cmd

```
    ren summary-* name1-summary*
```

and it takes away characters from the original file name, an example of what is output below:

"Name1-summary-S.txt"

"Nam1-summary-SS.txt"

"Na1-summary-ESS.txt"

"N1-summary-CESS.txt"

"N-summary-CCESS.txt"

"-summary-UCCESS.txt"

How would I go about adding a certain name to the beginning of a file name without losing any of the other characters in the original file name?

Comment: Use a [tag:for-loop]. Open a Command Prompt window and enter `for /?` to find out how to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) to iterate through all the matching files.

In a command prompt window ([cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)) it looks like this:

```cmd
for %I in ("summary-*.txt") do ren "%~I" "Name1-%~nxI"
```

In a batch script ([batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)) it looks like this:

```cmd
for %%I in ("summary-*.txt") do ren "%%~I" "Name1-%%~nxI"
```

You may be interested in this thread on Super User:
[How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874)